# How To Properly Replace The Content of a <pre> Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

How can I use jQuery (or even plain JS) to parse a given string as HTML and then replace the contents of all `<pre>` elements in the generated DOM (without encoding/decoding the entities in it) and convert it back to a string?

for example, say I have the following HTML stored as a string:

```
<p>HTML block</p>
<pre>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>Hi</p>
</body>
</pre>
```

and I would like to turn all `\n` characters into `<br/>`, so that the output string will be:

```
<p>HTML block</p>
<pre><br/><body><br/><h1>Hello World</h1><br/><p>Hi</p></br></body><br/></pre>
```

Note that `<pre>` elements can have anything in them, including other nested elements or scripts.

I tried using `$.parseHTML()` but for some reason it strips out certain nested elements (for example, `<body>` inside a `<pre>`)

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML.replace(/\r\n/, '<br/>')`

Comment: @vihan1086 it's not an HTML document, it's a string. How do I convert it to an HTML document?

Comment: I see, I added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know RegEx isn't the best <strike>but I'll add a DOM solution later</strike>. **Assuming `string` is your string**

```
string.replace(/(?:\<pre[\S\s]*?\>)([\S\s]*?)(?:\<\/pre\>)/, string.match(/(?:\<pre[\S\s]*?\>)([\S\s]*?)(?:\<\/pre\>)/)[1].replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'));
```

---

#### DOMParser

```
var d = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(string, 'text/html');
d.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML = d.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
```

`d` is like `document` and you can place this element in your DOM Structure.

---

To make it a string, you can do:

```
var d = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(string, 'text/html'); d.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
var newstring = d.body.innerHTML;
```

This will make a new variable, `newstring` that is your resulting string